# Robust Logic Circuit Design Tricks?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

Are there any good references or simple tricks for making robust logic circuits?
I am implementing a critical decision circuit with a single 4-input AND gate and I am worried about something going wrong with it, and would like to do something simple to make it more robust to failure of the chip.

What I mean by that:
If you are clever with ordinary components, you can sometimes make more capable devices that no one ever really tells you about, or that you won't find in a textbook. For example, paralleling transistors to increase output current, or putting resistors in series (instead of using one resistor with the equivalent value) to increase voltage rating, or paralleling power resistors to increase power dissipation capability. I am looking for a similar concept, but for increasing the reliability of logic circuits.

I know about triple redundancy and voting circuits, but I am looking for something that won't require >3x the components.

Comment: That depends on whether you mean, "if the chip fails nothing bad will happen", or "if the chip fails it will continue to work". Those are different requirements.

Comment: I am  not aware of anything of the nature you are discussing. Just make sure you follow normal good design practice including bypass capacitors, and, perhaps, some type of TVS on the VCC rail.

Comment: Cringes.  Each component you add, decreases reliability.

Comment: What makes your 4-input AND so important?  Are you making a million board production run?  Is it a medical device which could kill someone?  Do you have a UPS to ensure it can AND when the power goes?  What about the devices feeding this all powerful AND?  All gates are important.  Take mkeith's advice and let the AND be all the AND that it can be!  Give it a chance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a safety issue you can design your circuits so that two faults must happen before an output can be driven accidentally, as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foDRjD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, even with that, you need to worry about trace routing, connections, connectors and wiring shorts too. For example, in the circuit above, a short between the bottom of D3 and ground would cause unfortunate results.

If, on the other hand, you  want it to work despite a single fault, then that get's a lot more complicated.

**Looking at analogsystemsrf's suggestion** you may think you get some visibility into whether the and gates are working correctly.

[image]

HOWEVER, now you need to know if the OR gate is working... Worse, if the XOR gate fails you will either think there is a fault when there isn't, or not see the real fault. You also doubled the chance of failure by doubling the number of gates.. (Four times if you count the extra and gate). And what happens if the XOR gate failure mode is to pull an input high....

In the end, you are actually much farther away from fault tolerance than when you started.

You can use backup systems, but, if you only have one backup system then the phrase "Man with two watches never knows the right time!" comes to mind. It is impossible to tell which is right. That's why three or more backup systems are needed to implement voting systems.

In general, critical systems are designed to "FAIL-SAFE" and be replaced. If however, replacement is a bit awkward... e.g. in space, deep sea, etc., multiple redundant systems are often employed. Either using a voting system, which of course needs it's own fault detection and recovery systems, or remotely switched in after a fail-safe halt.

However, please be aware, adding more circuitry does not make a device more reliable. In fact the opposite is true. Every component you add reduces the reliability.

It may be more fault tolerant, but you will significantly reduce its "100% working" life.

Comment: That's my point "However, please be aware, adding more circuitry does not make a device more reliable. In fact the opposite is true. Every component you add reduces the reliability."

Comment: Yes @StainlessSteelRat, For some reason people have a hard time understanding that part. That's why I always tech people to concentrate on "fail-safe" and "fault detection and reporting" rather than fault tolerance. Except for the special applications where you have no choice...

Answer (score -1):

Consider adding a "CAN WE TRUST THIS DECISION" flag

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUarLg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: And how would you use that signal? (Alternatively: how would you determine its was actually correct, and not just stuck low?)

Comment: Good guestion. Should we add a "test the trust flag", as an event right before "each critical decision"?

Comment: Your circuit takes two inputs and results in two inputs. I don't see the real benefit of what you've drawn over just XORing the inputs together, which'd use 1 gate instead of 4 here.

Comment: I would think the real key would be to have different gates use different logic thresholds.  Have an inputs go through two buffers, one with a higher threshold than the other and double-synchronize the output of each buffer.  If the double synchronizers both report that the input is high, figure it is.  If they both reports is low, figure it is.  If they're split, figure it's necessary to wait another cycle to find out whether the input is high or low.

Comment: So what happens if OR2 fails.....